# "and" and tail recursion

Tags: recursion, scheme, tail-recursion

Can I build iterative process using recursive call in `and` statement?

For example, purpose, we have function `foo` that doesn't do anything. What kind of process it will create (iterative or recursion)?

```
(define (foo? bar) 
  (if (< bar 0) true (and (> 10 1) (foo? (- bar 1)))))
```

Comment: This will be recursive because the last function you call is `and` rather than `foo?`.

Comment: @Gabe: `and` is syntax, not a procedure.

Comment: @leppie: Assuming the compiler isn't optimizing away the entire thing in the first place, how does that change anything?

Comment: @Lambert: Regardless of optimization, Scheme has a standard syntax definition for `and`. See: http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-2.html#%_toc_%_sec_7.3

Comment: Thanks for the link... I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: I see, `and` evaluates its parameters until it gets #f or hits the end of the parameter list, so `foo?` really will be the last function called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `and` is OK - you can read this in the [standard](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-6.html#%_sec_3.5).

Comment: Could you please explain why that is iterative? I think it's not, because the recursive call isn't the last operation in the function.

Comment: +1 I think it's correct answer. from standard(by link in post) `(and <expression>* <tail expression>)`

Comment: Interesting... +1, even though I disagree. But can someone explain why?

Comment: It works because the the `foo?` call is the last subexpression of `and`, thus it's guaranteed to be the last function called. Also `and` is not a function, it is special form just like `if`.

Comment: @Lambert: Proper tail recursion, does not imply recursion in the sense of a loop.

Comment: @leppie: Huh? Tail recursion *is* by definition nothing more than a jump + variable update(s), isn't it? Otherwise, how can you add something and still use O(1) space?

Comment: @kotlinski: But I don't understand -- the last operation is *checking* the return value of `foo?`, not the call itself... so how do you say the call is the last operation?

Comment: The last operation is not really checking the return value. Since all expressions prior to `foo?` have already been called and proved to be #t, it only needs to do a straight call to `foo?`.

Comment: @Lambert: The result of the last expr in `and` is simple returned. Nothing needs to be checked.

Comment: @kotlinski, @leppi: Ohhhhhhhh I think I finally see now. It's a rather unusual result because `and` short-circuits, I see... thank you for the explanations!!!  :)

Answer (score 4):

For Lamberts sake, lets expand the syntax.

```
(define (foo? bar) 
  (if (< bar 0) 
      #t ; tail position, but no call
      (if (> 10 1) 
          (foo? (- bar 1)) ; tail position
          #f))) ; tail position, but no call
```

Comment: Yup, thank you for taking the time to write this! It certainly makes things clear! :D